# Cordova geolocation accuracy gets capped at 10 meters

Tags: android, cordova, geolocation, cordova-plugins

Update: it is a Google Play Service issue, reported internally [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation) and it will be fixed from version 13.4.0

We use the [cordova gelocation plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation) and the method `navigator.geolocation.watchPosition()` with the option `enableHighAccuracy: true` to track the user location and get the most accurate results.

Our app has been around for more than 1 year and we used to have no problems with any device getting a very good location accuracy, 4/6 meters when outside and the sky is clear.

Lately, many of our users are reporting not being able to get anything less than 10m accuracy no matter what they do.

We decided to test it ourselves and we found to have the same issue. Initially, we thought we introduced some bug in our latest release, we triple checked everything but we made no changes to code/dependencies involving geolocation.

We tested older versions of our app as well, where we are sure it was possible to get like 4m accuracy, but surprisingly they do not work either, accuracy is capped at 10m.

We tried different version of Android and we can reproduce the issue on any platform from 5 (Lollipop) to 8 (Oreo). We also have the same problem on iOS 10/11. Again, we have not updated the app in months.

There is a recent question about the same issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48925394/navigator-geolocation-getcurrentposition-in-cordova-gives-only-10-meter-accuracy):

Someone else is having the same problem using Android native code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49044731/fusedlocationapi-performance-issue-accuracy-seems-capped-at-10-0-meters)

Does anyone know what is going on? Is it a permission issue? Location Services are set to High Accuracy as well.

For the sake of completeness, we are able to get 3/4 meters accuracy using the old version (2.x) of this [plugin](https://github.com/mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation/tree/2.x)

Is it the only way to go?

We would rather not introduce an extra dependency for something that was working so well out of the box.

Many thanks

Comment: @tnt-rox Are you saying that the recievers in the phones are of bad quality and therefore the accuracy will suddenly be capped at 10.0 after a while?

Comment: @tnt-rox we used to get 4 meters on almost all our test devices, now I am not able to go below 10m no matter what I try, not even on my pixel 2.

Comment: Exactly, this would suggest that it is not a hardware problem at all. But instead it is a software problem. @tnt-rox

Comment: @tnt-rox the same happens in airplane mode

Comment: @Mirko Did you find a fix to this problem somehow? I mean did you some other way of getting better then 10m?

Comment: @thelastchief with this plugin https://github.com/mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation/tree/2.x I get down to 3 meters, I will look at the native code and use what I need.

Comment: I have the same issue with accuracy capped at 10 meters even though apps like GPS Test showing 3 meters. Have you managed to find solution with the original plugin?

Comment: @Patronaut there is not any solution with the original plugin, you have to use native code to go below 10 meters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To whom it might concern, it is a Google Play Services issue, reported internally [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/u/0/issues/79189573) and it will be fixed from version 13.4.0

Update: solved after updating to Play Services 14.3.66, accuracy down to 4m again!

Answer (score 4):

Looking at source code:

Old plugin (2.x) [Source](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation/blob/2.0.0/www/android/geolocation.js):

```
  watchPosition: function(success, error, args) {
    var win = function() {
        var geo = cordova.require('cordova/modulemapper').getOriginalSymbol(window, 'navigator.geolocation');
        geo.watchPosition(success, error, {
            enableHighAccuracy: args[1]
        });
    };
    exec(win, error, "Geolocation", "getPermission", []);
},
```

New Plugin (master) [Source](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation/blob/master/www/android/geolocation.js):

```
watchPosition: function(success, error, args) {
    var pluginWatchId = utils.createUUID();

    var win = function() {
        var geo = cordova.require('cordova/modulemapper').getOriginalSymbol(window, 'navigator.geolocation');
        pluginToNativeWatchMap[pluginWatchId] = geo.watchPosition(success, error, args);
    };

    var fail = function() {
        if (error) {
            error(new PositionError(PositionError.PERMISSION_DENIED, 'Illegal Access'));
        }
    };
    exec(win, fail, "Geolocation", "getPermission", []);

    return pluginWatchId;
},
```

In OLD plugin code **enableHighAccuracy** is a boolean set by (arg1 of array).

With NEW version of plugin you need to pass arg as JSON with that flag set:  **{enableHighAccuracy: true}** to reproduce same call to **geo.watchPosition** function with high accuracy.

**Old Way:**

```
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(geolocationSuccess,
                                                  geolocationError,
                                                  [false,true]);
```

**New Way:**

```
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(geolocationSuccess,
                                                  geolocationError,
                                                  { enableHighAccuracy: true });
```

Comment: We have always used the new way

Comment: Then try to not set highAccuracy at all, to reproduce same call to geo.. in Old version 2.x with new version of call accuracy are in fact not set.